# Uploading a photo from a form using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, parsing, post

I'm quite new to node and need some guidance and help. Before I go any further, I'm trying to do this without any other frameworks like Express. The situation is the following:

I've have a form where a user can upload a photo to a server running in node. The form has the following properties

```
<form  action="/newImages/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File goes : <input type="file" name="fileName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The form input is handled by this code

```
  if (req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/newImages/') {
  console.log("Inside Post method");
  var body = ''
  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data
  })
  req.on('end', function() {
     var note = querystring.parse(body)
      console.log(note)


      fs.writeFile("./test.jpg",body, function(err){
        if(err)
        {
          console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("The Picture was saved");
        }
      })

     res.writeHead(302, {
    'Content-Type':'text/plain',
    'location':'/index.html'});
    res.end('Found!');

  })
  }
```

However, something tells me I need to parse the data differently, as the output of this is unreadable. It looks like :
"\n\r\n����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000`\u0000`\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\b\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0006\u0005\b\u0007\u0007\u0007\t\t\b\n\f\u0014\r\f\u000b\u000b"

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I should also note that I upload .jpg's only.

Thanks

Comment: spec your encoding as binary in the writeFile call, like i told you in your other post an hour ago...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are wrong when you save your picture. You don't need to use fs.writeFile() but fs.rename.

This cose works in my app.js:

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    var tempPath = req.files.file.path,
        name = '',
        targetPath = '';

    fileExist = true; 
    fileNumber = 0;

    var fileType = path.extname(req.files.file.name);
    var fileName = path.basename(req.files.file.name,fileType);

    while (fileExist) {

      fileNumber_str = fileNumber.toString(); 

      var current = fileName + "_" +fileNumber_str + fileType;
      console.log("Controllo per "+current);

      if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/images/orig/" + current)) {
          console.log("--> Esiste");
          fileNumber++;
      } else {
          var newPath = __dirname + "/images/orig/" + current;
          console.log("nuovo nome : "+newPath);
          fs.rename(tempPath, newPath, function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //Ora creo il thumb
                console.log("Upload completed!");
            });
          break;
      }
    }

    res.redirect("/");
        res.end();    
});
```

Take a look.

M.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot parse multipart data with `querystring.parse`.

You have to write your own parser or use third-party module, like [node-multiparty](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty).

With multiparty module the code will be like this:

```
if (req.method == 'POST' && req.url == '/newImages/') {
  var form = new multiparty.Form();
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var tmp = files.fileName[0].path;
    fs.rename(tmp, '/your/dir/img.jpg', function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('success');
    });
    res.end('Found!');
 });
}
```